# how to make the inputs work with a background image?

Tags: html, angular, css

I've been working with a form and it has an image for the background, the  main problem is I can not fill the inputs, cause it does not work correctly

[https://angular-iq8jgr.stackblitz.io](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iq8jgr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

I can fill the inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `z-index` property of your container with class name `hero`. you need to remove the negative z-index. I don't know why you put that but, you don't seem to need that anyway.